New Starter, spins but no crank
2018 Nissan Versa 1.6L (67K) CVT Automatic  - SIL was reporting at 67K engine was making weird noise while at idle.  If she reved it went away.
A few weeks later she driving home and the engine seemed to surge climbing a hill, revved up and totally died.  Later, I went to start it but the starter sounded weird (like no load).  Checked battery... it knew it needed a new one, so while I was at it, I also pulled starter only to find some damaged teeth. Bought a refurbished starter from AutoZone and new Duralast battery.  Both tested good at store.  Installed battery  (13.1v), starter sounded exactly the same as old one.  Had wife turn ignition key and noticed the crankshaft pulleys were not moving with starter engaged.  Pulled starter... found the flex-plate moves by hand while the crankshaft does not. Thinking damaged flex-plate at the crankshaft flange? So before I tear this thing apart and drop the CVT, am I missing something obvious?
Car history:  53K the CVT Transmission crapped out. Nissan replaced under warranty about a year ago.  Maybe they forgot to install the dowel pins in the case which caused the flex-plate to eventually fail??

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

When you have the batt disconnected for the repairs, evaluate the ignition switch carefully. It may have been the root cause of everything else. See if it sticks in the START position or is sluggish returning to ON from START under its own spring power. The "weird noise" at idle was likely from the starter remaining engaged while the engine ran. That's likely what chewed up the teeth. Who knows how many times that happened, and what further damage that caused to the ring gear and flexplate.

Paulster - Good Copy. I knew something was screwy with the starter too as I started the breakdown today and found the never attched the ground to tye engine block.  It was bolted to the frame  but the end of the lead from the battery was not on the block.
I started to wonder if that was it tye whole time and maybe i didnt need to drop the CVT afterall… Laying on my back with a ratchet on the crankshaft I slowly turned the engine clockwise while putting resistance on the flexplate.    Initially felt solid… then flexplate totally stopped and could feel grinding.  Drop CVT tomorrow

Dropped CVT today…. Found a mess insde.  Lots of damage to torque converter and bell housing.  The flex plate was in bad shape and appears the main bearings went too.  Scrap heap.
